# SAP Oracle migration to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I have SAP applications using Oracle. There is a need to migrate from Oracle to Open source DB (say PostgreSQL).
Is there any way I can do the assessment of the complexity of the migration (feasibility analysis, i.e how much SAP applications are tied up with Oracle DB etc.?)

Comment: Are you **sure** SAP supports Postgres?

Comment: There are a number of applications in addition to SAP applications. I need to do a feasibility study. I am not sure if SAP supports PostgreSQL ? Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand:

The SAP server has a special abstraction layer called Database Interface which converts Open SQL Statements into Database specific Native SQL. Therefore, SAP software is Database Independent

Оn the other hand:

Look at Database and OS Platforms [SAP Wiki topic](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ATopics/Database+and+OS+Platforms)

- DB2
- Sybase ASE
- Oracle
- Microsoft SQL Server
- MaxDB
- of course SAP HANA

Accordingly SAP on  PostgreSQL is the terra incognita